# Vue not navigating to new tab on window open

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have made a BitPay integration within my app, and I would like to navigate to a new tab instead of the same window on user click.

```
purchaseWithBitPay() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getBitPayRedirectUri',
        {
            quantity : this.sliderValue,
            returnUrl: this.$route.path
        })
        .then((response) => {
            window.open(response.data.redirect, '_blank');
        });
},
```

This doesn't work. Purchase method is ran on-click, and once the promise is resolved it just opens in same window. How to make it navigate to a separate tab?

Comment: This isn’t a VueJS issue. Chances are, your window open logic is invoked too late for browsers to open in a new window or tab, since it occurs too late after user interaction.

Comment: Any way to override it?

Comment: can you try window.open(someurl, '_blank') before you dispatch and see how it is behaving? @Norgul

Comment: window.open() must instantiate a new tab by default. At least that's how it happens in Chrome. If it isn't what occurs, maybe something is wrong with the response payload. Did you check it doing a console.log of your response.data.redirect?

Comment: Well it is opening the right URL within the same window, so I don't see how it could be malformed in any way

Comment: Can you wrap the `window.open` method with a `this.$nextTick` callback and see what happens?